# Store user input on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple "themes" for my website which the user can choose in their account settings, though I would like that when they select the theme it doesn't have to store the information in a database but rather somewhere else.

How would I do this? This is my code for the user "theme" selection.

```
<form name="themeselection" id="themeselection" method="post" action="account.php">
   <select id="theme" name="theme">
     <option value="1">Theme 1</option>
     <option value="2">Theme 2</option>
     <option value="3">Theme 3</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Not sure if the code helps but is there a way to store the information as the pages switch preferably with minimal code?

---

Comment: cant you use cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Set your theme value to a session or cookie variable.
This will keep the data for all pages

```
setcookie('cookiename',valuetoset,time()+10*60) //here it saves the cookie for 10 minutes
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the cookies only last for a certain time limit?

Comment: Thanks so this will delete after 10 minutes?